# regex match list of classes using and/or

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to match a set of specific classes -

I want to match classes `inline` **AND/OR** a (set of) `colors` only, either on their own or 2 together:

`<span class="inline">` should match

`<span class="green">` should match

`<span class="inline green">` should match

`<span class="blue inline">` should match

--

`<span class="inline green blue">` should ***not*** match (no more than 2 classes)

`<span class="green blue">` should ***not*** match (two colors - doesn't have *inline* class)

I've got this at the moment but it's not working:

regex `/((inline)?(\s|green|blue|red|yellow))/`

Any suggestions? Many thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you're doing this with regex, anstead of `className` or `getAttribute('class')`?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yes :)

Comment: would you mind awfuly _giving_ that reason, because you might miss out on the easier, more reliable and more performant option here...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem For the purpose of this app, the 'html' being parsed here is actually text and isn't within the DOM to be able to be selected in this way with straight JS.

Comment: Thought as much, but that wouldn't prevent you from doing this: `var tmpDiv = document.createElement('div'); tmpDiv.innerHTML = htmlString; var spans = tmpDiv.getElementsByTagName('span');`, by inserting the spans in a temp div, the markup _will_ be parsed... that's a lot easier than cocking about with regex's, and it's more reliable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following regex?

```
/^(?:inline|green|blue|red|yellow)(?:\s+(?:inline|green|blue|red|yellow))?$/
```

It breaks down as follows:

- `^`: Start of the class string
- `(?:)`: Non-capturing group. Allows you to group things together without creating a capturing group. This makes things faster.
- `inline|green|blue|red|yellow`: An enumeration of all your possible values
- `\s+`: One or more whitespace characters. Just \s by itself is a bit limiting, I think.
- `(?:\s+(?:inline|green|blue|red|yellow))?`: This makes everything after the first class name completely optional.

**Edit**:

As per nnnnnn's comment, I think my original regex is ill-suited for the job. However, I think that the following regex should be okay:

```
/^(?:inline(?:\s+(?:green|blue|red|yellow))?)|(?:green|blue|red|yellow(?:\s+inline)?)$/
```

Obviously, it's a lot more complicated, but that's why it might be best to simply split the className string of the element on `\s+`, count the number of elements in the resulting array, and then check each on individually.

Comment: Wouldn't this allow `"inline inline"`?

Comment: nnnnnn, yes, you're absolutely right. I hadn't thought of that. After reading the original question more carefully, I think I now understand what Tim wants, and while it can be attained with only a regex, it seems like it would be a really long and complicated regex. I think it would be easier to simply split the className property string on \s+, and then check the individual parts. Anyway, I will try to edit the regex in my post accordingly.